# restore ubuntu 20.04 to 2 days ago

Tags: 20.04, restore

Can I use /var/backups files to restore my system to its days of 2 days ago?
i see in that folder files like alternative.tar.gz and dpkg.status and many more files, while everything with 2 in it is to days ago (like *.2.gz).
can i use those files in any way to roll back my system to 2 days ago?
if so how?
if not is there any way to restore the system to a working state if I did not make a backup?
yesterday for some reason my Linux system files got corrupted and I can't seem to fix that through recovery mode.

to elaborate a little more:
I did not make any backups of my own.
i just encountered this folder while trying to find a way to restore/fix my ubuntu 20.04 system files which are making problems all of a sudden
image of the folder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sws8i.jpg

Comment: Hello. Have you been making full system back ups every 2 days?

Comment: How did you make the backup? We need to know that information to help you fix the issue

Comment: updated in topic, if it helps i can also upload VM settings.

Comment: No, you can not restore Ubuntu, if you did not use a Backup Tool (e.g. "Backups" a.k.a. "Deja Dup"). Your files are just app-specific backups which will not help rolling back. You should ask a question about your issue ("for some reason my Linux system files got corrupted"). Maybe we can help with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!
Please direct me to what information will help you diagnose my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be extremely hard to restore your system to the state it was two days ago, unless you used a dedicated tool designed to handle such situation.

One such tool is Timeshift. It is available in the Universe repository.

Timeshift takes a snapshot of the system at preset times in a space efficient way. The system can later be restored to the state captured in one of these snapshots.

While maintaining multiple versions of your system file system, it does so in a space efficient manner. It can use native features of the `btrfs` file system. On `ext4`, the default file system of Ubuntu, it uses `rsync`. Each of the snapshots is a full copy of the system files. However, system files that have not changed are hardlinked to their versions in a previous snapshot. This is how the tool is space efficient. It is installed by default in Linux Mint systems.

Comment: OK so i guess restoring is not an option, any ideas on how to analyze and fix my system.